# How to update embeded subreport when clicked on a column in main report

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to have on click events in SSRS, e.g. having a master report (Orders) and then a sub report (Order Details) embed into it, when I click on order it will show specific order's details in sub report.

I am able to show first order details on load by following these articles and videos,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S8Zzqthsbw
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD#3

But I am struggling to add ON CLICK event which will change sub report's parameter.

**Update**

I found this article which shows how to add dynamic actions in SSRS,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/expression-based-dynamic-drillthrough.aspx

But what I am really trying to do is to create a master details report in SSRS so that I could export it to EXCEL, keep it's master detail behavious so when someone click on order ID in master worksheet, take them to details worksheet in excel to show order details.
I am planning to move this details report to new sheet by using pagebreak and page name but I am not sure how above behaviour is going to help...